# Problems with starting my Motorcycle

Tags: honda, motorcycle, battery, starting

I have a Honda 2003 VTX 1300 S Retro that will not start without a jump. I just purchased a new battery on line (Chinese) for this type of bike charged it and still getting the same results as before. Yet if I jump the bike with my car its starts? Please help
Thanks
Ruben...

Comment: Are there any signs of battery terminal corrosion?

Comment: When you jump start it, are you connecting the jump cable connectors to the battery terminals on the bike, or some other place?

Comment: If the terminal check out I would personally start leaning towards starter as it is requiring more amps than what your battery can provide.

Comment: The replacement battety could also be at fault. Just because its new and has a charge doesn't mean that it can supply enough amps when required.

Comment: Did the battery come with a container of battery acid that you poured into the battery before installation?